# LINQ - DateTime to String again

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
            result = from i in _dbContext.Meetings
                     where i.UserInvitedID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day >= date
                     //where i.UserInvitedID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day) >= date
                     select new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2()
                     {
                         Name = i.UserInviter.FirstName + " " + i.UserInviter.LastName,
                         Company = i.UserInviter.Company,
                         MeetingID = i.MeetingID,
                         Time = EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(EntityFunctions.AddHours(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day, i.AllowedTime.Hour).Value, i.AllowedTime.Minute).Value.ToString("0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy 0:t"),
                         Image = i.UserInviter.ProfileImage,
                         Username = i.UserInviter.aspnet_User.UserName
                     };
```

Time is string. Of course, I get

> Exception error: {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression."}

but how to write correctly in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.ToString` in L2E at all. That's an EF limitation.

You have to do that in object space -- e.g., after an `.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: and how can i do it? In select part I have to set Time, right?

Comment: You do something like: `select new { A = i.A, B = i.B }).AsEnumerable().Select(i => new MeetingModel2 { A = i.A.ToString(...), B = i.B );`

Comment: will be very long script ( I have approx similar 10 places, which can't be combined in one)

Comment: Another option would be to make a computed column in your DB.